# Which of the following have similar meaning to 'neither do I' and can be used as a reply?

Tags: word-choice

> I don't play games like that.

Which of the following have similar meaning to 'neither do I' and can be used as a reply?

- 'Neither I do.'
- 'As I don't.'

Comment: As a reply to which question? There is no question that you should be replying. The sentence starting with "Don't...." is not a question. It is an imperative.

Comment: "Neither do I" is not an appropriate response to a request not to do something. You might answer "I'm  _not_ playing games" or simply "I'm not doing."

Comment: updated.........

Comment: (Following update) Why do you need an alternative to "Neither do I"? "As I don't" means the same but is _very_ unidiomatic..

Comment: @KateBunting because i am tired of neither do I. How about neither I do?

Comment: Tough.  "Neither do I" is what we say, "Neither I do" is nonsense.

Comment: "Nor me" or less formally ["me either" or "me neither"](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Me-Neither-Me-Either-Me-Too) would be alternatives. "Ditto" would be another less standard option. "Same here" is also used informally for agreement. Some of these may depend on your precise dialect/location/age/class/etc.

Comment: I don't **either**. is the alternate way to say this.